# How to use error-prone in maven without changing the compiler?

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin, errorprone

I want to use error-prone on my Java project.

However, I am reluctant to to change the compiler configuration and want to keep the normal `javac` configuration from `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Basically, it means using use error-prone in the verify phase, as for instance with the findbugs or checkstyle plugin.

How to use error-prone in maven without changing the compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but based on the docs of error-prone it is configured in the maven-compiler-plugin setup..So what's the problem here ? You have written you want to use it So ?

Comment: The problem is to replace the compiler itself, which is the thing in which I want to have the maximum possible trust (and not just a fancy dependency).

Comment: Maybe I don't get your point ...If i see correctly error-prone is something like pmd/cpd/findbugs etc. ok on a different level...and what do you understand under a `fancy dependency`? Those dependencies are defined by their version ? Or do you have not trust in error-prone itself ? If so...in the end it's a tool which might have bugs/problems etc. as any other piece of software....Maven/JavaC/JVM itself of course etc. ?